# (Python Tkinter) Klick a button, then run different functions one after another and show the results in realtime in my GUI

Tags: python, function, user-interface, tkinter

following Problem. I created a Tkinter GUI. There is a button, a text widget and a label which shows my progress status. 
There is a function that clears the text widget, a function that writes in the text widget and a function that updates the progress status.

At first the status label says: "-"
When I click the button. I want the label to say "Work in progress" as long as the funtion that writes in the text widget is working. after the text is shown in the widget (takes a while) the status should say: "done".

The problem is, that I currently click the button. after a few seconds the text is shown in the text widget and the status just switches from "-" to "done".

```
def show_working_status(self):
    self.status["text"] = "Work in progress"

def show_done_status(self):
    self.status["text"] = "Done"

def cleartext(self):
    .......

def write(self, columns)
    .......


def write_text(self, columns)
    self.cleartext()
    self.show_working_status()
    self.write(columns)
    self.show_done_status()
```

I hope i made my problem as clear as possible :)

Greetings,
Tom

Answer (score 0):

You should use multithreading:

```
import threading

t1 = threading.Thread(target=your_first_function)
t1.start()
t2 = threading.Thread(target=your_second_function)
t2.start()
t3 = threading.Thread(target=your_third_function)
t3.start()
```

This will make the functions `your_first_function`, `your_second_function` and `your_third_function` run in parallel. This makes it so that your window won't freeze, since the Tkinter Mainloop is just an infinite while loop.

You can also make one function that will call all of yours in order.

Comment: Hey! I really appreciate your answer, but unfortunately it doesn't work for me. I changed my code with your solution, but the problem stays the same. I click the button, nothing happens for a while, text gets shown in my widget and in the same moment the status label switches from: "-" to "done" :/ but the status " work in progess" is still missing.

Comment: what is the function that your button calls? `write_text`?

Comment: try debugging with `print`s (print something after each statement) in `write_text` -- that way you can know what runs when, and send here what happens (in the GUI) in each function

Comment: when i print 1-4 after each thread it prints to my console at first 1,2 and in the moment the text shows in the text widget it shows 3 and 4. which is correct. is just doesnt work with my gui

Comment: my gui just ignores step 1 and 2.. or better to say it executes all 4 at the same time and not step by step

Comment: forgot to mention in the answer, the Button's command should be `mythread.start`

Comment: are you using that?

Comment: I'm not sure if I know what you mean. I guess there is anoter problem with my code. In reality its much more complex, I just made it look less complicated to just solve my specific problem.

Comment: Suppose ou have defined a thread named `t1`. Then, when you define `tkinter.Button(master, text="-", command=write_text)`, switch `write_text` by `t1.start`, which is the member `start` of the object `t1`, which you were calling previously as `t1.start()`